# Combine two files in a particular order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have two files

the first one called `plays.txt` that looks something like,

```
D:\data\nfl\Weekly\2014Week1\ARI.txt
D:\data\nfl\Weekly\2014Week1\ATL.txt
...
D:\data\nfl\Weekly\2014Week1\WAS.txt

===
D:\data\nfl\Weekly\2014Week2\ARI.txt
...
```

And I also have a file named `spreads.txt` that looks something like,

```
D:\data\nfl\spreads\2014Week1\NFL Games 2014Week1.csv
D:\data\nfl\spreads\2014Week2\NFL Games 2014Week2.csv
D:\data\nfl\spreads\2014Week3\NFL Games 2014Week3.csv
D:\data\nfl\spreads\2014Week4\NFL Games 2014Week4.csv
D:\data\nfl\spreads\2014Week5\NFL Games 2014Week5.csv
...
```

I am trying to combine them into one file that looks like,

```
D:\data\nfl\Weekly\2014Week1\ARI.txt
D:\data\nfl\Weekly\2014Week1\ATL.txt
...
D:\data\nfl\Weekly\2014Week1\WAS.txt

D:\data\nfl\spreads\2014Week1\NFL Games 2014Week1.csv
===
D:\data\nfl\Weekly\2014Week2\ARI.txt
D:\data\nfl\Weekly\2014Week2\ATL.txt
...
D:\data\nfl\Weekly\2014Week2\WAS.txt

D:\data\nfl\spreads\2014Week2\NFL Games 2014Week2.csv
===
...
```

How do I combine these two files so that I put the file location of the spread `.csv` files after all the `TEAM.txt` files for each year/week?

Comment: Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource. However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to open the plays.txt and spreads.txt in an editor and paste spreads.txt in the end (after plays.txt). Save as a new file called newfile.txt and open in excel or openoffice. After that you can sort it. Hopefully you will get what you want. Python can do it too but it will be an overkill.
Best wishes.

Comment: I was able to write a script, see my answer.

Comment: Good job. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

For the curious as to how I solved this here is the script I came up with,

```
import os


games = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('plays.txt', 'r')]
spreads = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('spreads.txt', 'r')]

for spread in spreads:
    year_week = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(spread).split()[-1])[0]
    for idx, game in enumerate(games):
        parts = os.path.splitext(game)[0].split('\\')
        if parts[-1] == 'WAS' and parts[-2] == year_week:
            games.insert(idx + 1, "")
            games.insert(idx + 2, spread)
```

Basically, I wanted to insert the csv file after the last team, which was always WAS.txt, then I just pulled out the week/year to make sure that I was inserting them in the correct `{year}Week{week}` position.